# Autoscaling based on Load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

We have autoscaling set based on **CPU utilization** (threshold 65%) and we are using `c4.large` instances.

During heavy load on the Load balancer ie 300 TPS (transactions per second), the CPU utilization is not crossing threshold and scale-out of EC2 instances is not happening.

As a result, requests started failing (for some reason). Memory is spiked up and down (as garbage collector kicks in when memory is high).

We want to scale-out based on the **Load to Load balancer** as the load increases incrementally like 300 TPS to 350 to 400.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is the memory spike sustained? You could scale based on memory usage.  You can also look at your network traffic and scale on it.

Comment: Memory spike is not sustained and I don't want to scale on memory..and can you elaborate on scaling based on network traffic ?

Comment: Why do you want to scale? Are any requests actually failing? If so, how do you know that scaling-out will actually fix the problem -- do you know where the requests are being rejected? If nothing is failing, then you'll need to simulate load until something fails, then look at metrics to find a metric that can identify when you'll need to scale.

Comment: Yes requests are failing when load is very high ..but CPU and memory were intact..so would like to autoscale and see

Comment: I think you need to find where the bottleneck.  Check your network traffic to those servers and the disk IO.  Those are the last two major resource level variables.  If your network is getting slammed then you can setup a scaling alarm on Network IO.  Same for disk IO.

Comment: Also... if one of these metrics are not spiking then you have a configuration issue inside the EC2 instance. Perhaps your webserver/app/DB needs tuning to take advantage of the resources on the EC2 instance.

Comment: You mentioned "requests stated failing". What kind of error do you get? Is it a timeout due to latency? Does it come from the load balancer or the instance?

Comment: So we have Tomcat webserver on the Ec2 Instances wherein the default value for number of parallel threads allowed is 200.So during performance test when we increase the load to 200TPS(transaction per second) and when it reaches the max number of threads in tomcat the requests started failing (rejected by load Balancer)(we observe this threads reaching threshold in Appdynamics)..So not sure how to autoscale in this scenario